# Projecting a cone on a surface

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I want to find the projection of a base of a cone on a plane. I'm looking for its area. I know only the height of the cone and two angles and the distance from the vertex to the plane. Could you give me some pointers?

[image: Cone Net]

Comment: Give more detail ; there is insufficient detail in your question.

Comment: You also need some distance like the distance between the projection plane and the cone vertex.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do you mean a **central** projection from point $O$  (not an **orthogonal** projection) as I can understand looking at the blue segment ? 2) Are you aware that you will find an ellipse ?

Comment: @toliveira it is also known. BTW I thought that you could even calculate it using the cosine function.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes I'm aware that I will find an ellipse - I'm looking for it's area.

Comment: You haven't answered me about the kind of projection : does the red "curve" (circle) becomes the blue "curve" (ellipse): if yes it is a central projection.

Comment: The area of the ellipse is a function of the length of its major axis length and the length of its minor axis. Start by finding the length of them.

Comment: @lough_or_cry, you are right, you can calculate the distance to the plane using the cosine function. Sorry, I haven't paid attention to R.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, the circle becomes the ellipse

Comment: A couple of other questions that involve measurement of the ellipse formed by the intersection of a cone and a plane are http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789899 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278943.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's apply the sine rule to the upper triangle on the right: if $p_1$ is its horizontal (blue) side we have
$$
{p_1\over\sin(\pi/2+\Omega)}={R\tan\Omega\over\sin(\pi/2-\Omega-\alpha)},
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
p_1=R\tan\Omega{\cos\Omega\over\cos(\alpha+\Omega)}.
$$
In an analogous way, by applying the sine rule to the upper triangle on the left, its horizontal (blue) side turns out to be:
$$
p_2=R\tan\Omega{\cos\Omega\over\cos(\alpha-\Omega)}.
$$
The major axis $2a$ of the ellipse is then $2a=p_1+p_2$.

To find semi-major axis $b$ we can substitute $x=(p_1-p_2)/2$ and $y=R\tan\Omega$ into the equation
$$
{x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1,
$$
which gives:
$$
b={R\tan\Omega(p_1+p_2)\over2\sqrt{p_1p_2}}.
$$

From $a$ and $b$ you can compute the area of the ellipse.

[image]

Comment: See also [this other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4079846/255730) for further explanations.