Curvature of a cone
I'm trying to get the mean curvature $K/2=\kappa_1 + \kappa_2$ of a cone with a half angle $\alpha$ at a distance $d$ from the apex.
The curvature along the generator is zero $\kappa_1=0$. As for the curvature of the normal section, I'm trying to calculate it with Meusnier's theorem but I'm stuck as I don't fully understand it. I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to get it.
Here's a schematic:

Thanks to everyone that replied.

Here’s one way: In $xyz$-space, put the generator on the $x$-axis with the vertex at the origin and the cone lying above $xy$-plane. The bottom half of the cone is the graph of a function, $z=f(x,y)$. Find $f$. Each point on the generator is a minimum point and therefore a critical point. It follows that the Hessian of $f$ at these points is the second fundamental form.

Please include a picture/diagram of this.

The cone's metric is formally equal to the flat Euclidean metric in polar coordinates. Exercise: calculate Chrisoffel symbols and Riemann tensor.

The normal section is a conic. For an ellipse the curvature at vertex is $a/b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are the semiaxes which can be computed as explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177867/projecting-a-cone-on-a-surface/4077306?noredirect=1#comment8429285_4077306

When you say curvature, do you mean the Gaussian curvature? Or are you wanting to find the principal curvatures individually? And, since there may be some confusion, I assume you mean a right circular cone?

Thanks for the comments. I updated my question.

According to Meusnier's theorem, if you consider all plane sections of a surface having a common tangent, then the radius of curvature of a section is $r\cos\gamma$, where $r$ is the radius of curvature of the normal section and $\gamma$ is the angle formed with the normal section.
In your case we can take as oblique section the one perpendicular to the axis of the cone, which is a circle with radius $r=d\sin\alpha$ forming an angle $\gamma=\alpha$ with the normal section. Hence the radius of curvature of the normal section is
$$
r_N={r\over\cos\alpha}=d\tan\alpha.
$$

Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Now the theorem makes much more sense. Thank you for your time.

The cone is the submanifold of spherical coordinates with constant angle $\theta$:  $$x= r \cos \phi\  \sin \theta, \ y = r \sin \phi \ \sin \theta,\ z=r \cos \theta.$$ It follows that its metrics written as the quadratic form
$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 \sin^2 \theta\  d\phi^2$$
The Lagrangian formalism yields the Euler geodetic equations in terms of the arc parameter $t$
$$\frac{d}{dt} \partial_{\dot r}\ \left(\frac{1}{2} \dot r^2 \right)  -\partial_{ r}\left(\frac{1}{2} \left( r^2 \sin^2  \theta \ \dot \phi^2\right)\right)=0 $$ and
$$\frac{d}{dt} \partial_{\dot \phi}\ (\frac{1}{2}  r^2 \sin^2 \theta \ \dot \phi ^2)  =0$$
or $$\ddot r = r \ \sin^2 \theta \ \dot \phi^2$$
$$\ddot \phi = -r \ \sin ^2\theta \ \dot r \ \dot \phi$$
yielding the only two nonvanishing Christoffel symbols in
$${\ddot x}^k = {\Gamma^k}_{lm}\ {\dot x}^l \ {\dot x}^m$$
$${\Gamma^r}_{\phi\phi} = r \sin^2\theta, \quad {\Gamma^\phi}_{r \phi} = {\Gamma^\phi}_{\phi r}- \frac{1}{2} \ r\ \sin^2\theta$$
With these connection forms the Riemann tensor evaluates to zero, the cone is flat and evolvable on a euclidean plane as part of disk (the or lower upper half of the double cone).

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I couldn't quite follow your derivation, but I am sure it will be useful for other people that may have the same question.

Reading the question carefully, it appears that OP asks for the mean curvature (extrinsic), not the sectional curvature (intrinsic)
